# sql Developer pkg AND trg FILES

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

taking a SQL class and using sql developer. How do I create a file with extensions .pkg and .trg. I know they are for package and triggers. When I opened my connection and right clicked package I opened a package but it did not create an actual file that I would be able to submit?

Any ideas?

Comment: Just save the code in a text file with whatever arbitrary extension you want.  There is nothing special about a `.trg` or `.pkg` extension (and there are many different conventions for these things).  They're all just text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various options for saving your code to a file:

1. Right click on the object in the connections tree and choose Quick DDL -> Save to File. This will save the file with a .sql extension which you can later change as desired from the file system.
2. Open the object from the connections tree, then choose File -> Save As.  This method defaults to saving files with a .pls extension, but you can override that when saving or change it later from the file system.
3. Drag the objects from the Connections tree to the shopping Cart (View->Cart) then Click the Export Cart button (DB icon with a green arrow) and choose the Save As Separate Files option.  The files will be saved with .sql extensions, and for table objects it can optionally export the data as well.